# Compile php with latest openssl and curl

Tags: php, openssl, curl

I am trying to compile php 5.4.36 with latest curl and openssl (1.0.1l), i have compiled openssl into a  separated folder

My system is CentOS.

When i try to compile php with

```
./configure  ...etc... --with-curl=/usr/local/curlfolder --with-openssl=/usr/local/opensslfolder
```

I get this error:

```
checking whether to enable FTP support... yes
checking OpenSSL dir for FTP... /usr/local/opensslfolder
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries
```

Both curl and openssl compiled without any issues

Comment: Try to the SRPMS as a starting point, manually installing software is generally not encouraged. Might be easier to just upgrade to the newest CentOS version.

Answer (score 5):

these "dirs" are merely prefixes... while cURL basically comes with it's own SSL.

PHP needs to be configured like that, to build for CentOS - with openSSL and cURL:

```
./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin --with-curl=/usr/local
```

(assuming the additional libraries were built with):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Comment: Thank you. The "configure --help" output was not clear on this.

Comment: @Sarah that is because it's two independent configure scripts, one for the PHP interpreter and one for the libraries which cURL depends on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
--with-openssl or --with-openssl-dir
```

If you build openssl from source in folder like /opt/openssl
then You can try with

```
--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl
```

This was worked for me.